# Tail probabilities of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: r, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

I would like to compute tail probabilities of the standardized multivariate normal distribution for different dimensions. For example, in the case of bivariate normal I need to compute the gray area on the figure pasted below (In this particular case, the area is defined by $\mathbf{x} > 2$.)

[image: figure-1]

I found somewhere (but unfortunately, I lost the reference) that the probability that the data point $\mathbf{x}$ is outside the spherical contour with radius $\alpha$ should be calculated as:

$$
\begin{split}
\Pr \left(\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{f(\mathbf{0})} \geq \alpha\right) &= 
P(\mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{x} \leq -2 \ln (\alpha)) \\
&= \int_{0}^{-2 \ln(\alpha)} f_{\chi_{d}^{2}(\mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{x})} \\
&= F_{\chi_{d}^{2}} (-2 \ln (\alpha))
\end{split}
$$
where $F$ is cumulative distribution function.

I find myself lost in this equation. I kindly ask for computational example how to compute desired probability (in whatever programming language).

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution myself:

```
pchisq(q = alpha^2, df = d)
```

`alpha` stands for radius and `d` stands for dimension.

Comment: The `mvtnorm` package in `R` can do this. Check [this document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/vignettes/MVT_Rnews.pdf) for many examples. I think you want the `pmvnorm` function.

Comment: I will check the `mvtnorm` function, but I would also like to understand how to compute it manually.

Comment: Andrej, are you interested only in the case where the components are iid standard normal (as your figure depicts) or are you interested in the more general case with an arbitrary covariance matrix $\Sigma$?

Comment: Only in iid standardized normal case.

Comment: The probability you quote concerns the event that the standard multinormal density at a standard multinormally distributed point $\mathbf{x}$, relative to the density at the origin $\mathbf{0}$, is smaller than $\alpha$.  Thus, $\alpha$ is necessarily an non-positive number.  If you define $\alpha$ as the radius in your graph, however, then your R code is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments, copied here :

The mvtnorm package in R can do this. Check https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/vignettes/MVT_Rnews.pdf   for many examples.